# Chinese character input in Kubuntu 16.10 on Plasma 5.8?

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, ibus, plasma, chinese

How can I enable Chinese character input in Kubuntu 16.10 on Plasma 5.8?

I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59081/how-can-i-configure-a-chinese-input-method) but it seems quite old.

I can enable Chinese character input in Xubuntu 16.10 easily by installing `ibus-pinyin` and **selecting Chinese options in** **Input Method** (I have no language options in my Kubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin
```

But how can I do that in Kubuntu?

I have this message on my Kubuntu when I launch **Input Method**:

```
Current configuration for the input method:
 * Active configuration: missing (normally missing)
 * Normal automatic choice: none (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
 * Override rule: zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx:ja_JP,fcitx:ko_KR,fcitx:vi_VN,fcitx
 * Current override choice:  (en_GB)
 * Current automatic choice: none
 * Number of valid choices: 1 (normally 1)
The override rule is defined in /etc/default/im-config.
The configuration set by im-config is activated by re-starting X.
Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration, if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
```

Any ideas?

I can't find **Language Support** in my  kubuntu 16.10  as well! why??